# Boundary condition on parallel component of B field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

I am confused about the physical significance of discontinuity in the parallel component of B field. So the setup is let's say I have a cylinder with "frozen-in" magnetization M and a linear current density K given by K = k(in azimuthal direction). If I use the equation, B(parallel above)- B(parallel below) = (magnetic permeability of free space)* (K x unit normal vector), I see that the two parallel components of B are not equal. What does this signify? Let's say if I were to draw how B field or H would look like, where does this fact come into action?